# What is the difference between Policy15 and Policy12?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a basic service host:

```
m_host = new ServiceHost(m_service, m_baseAddress);
ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
behavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
m_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IManagerService), 
    new BasicHttpBinding(), m_soapAddress);
m_host.Open();
```

My question is how do I know which PolicyVersion to use?  The MSDN is not very helpful, it seems to think I should know already if I want 1.2 or 1.5...

[PolicyVersion.Policy15 Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.DESCRIPTION.POLICYVERSION.POLICY15%29;k%28POLICY15%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

[PolicyVersion.Policy12 Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.policyversion.policy12%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know the answer but appreciate the question. But [here's a list of changes from 1.2 to 1.5](http://markmail.org/message/rwlwlc4yop4vfgyr) in case you understand what they are talking about.

Comment: Are there old clients that only support 1.2 that I need to be aware of?  Or is this all server side processing and I should always use the latest my framework supports?

Comment: I think as long as you are consuming your own services, you probably don't have to worry about the policy version. If you have to expose your service to others that have specific policy version requirements, that's a different story. I would probably just go with the defaults unless you're actually having specific problems with the policy version and your metadata. In that case, you probably want to put that in your question.

Comment: I solved the actual problem I was having with metadata, this was just one stop on my investigation that I was not able to resolve.  FYI this solved my actual problem, which is not directly related to this question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Tombala when you say leave it at default, are you suggesting the policy version be not even set?  All the MSDN examples manually set this value.

Comment: Actually, have you considered just exposing your service MEX endpoint using web.config preferences instead of writing code? Are you hosting your service outside of IIS through some windows service or something?

Comment: I'm using code instead of doing it all in config because the requirements call for some of the parameters to come from the customer's config file instead.

Comment: Ouch! Darn those requirements. :) I'm not sure what the default value for PolicyVersion would be. You should post your final code in its working condition and accept it as the answer.

Comment: I think you should post your link from your first comment and I'd accept that as the answer.  The question had little to do with the problem I was debugging when I thought to ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case others wonder what changes there were from 1.2 to 1.5, [here's a link](http://markmail.org/message/rwlwlc4yop4vfgyr) that gives a list of changes.

From Denise, MSDN has an article about how to publish your own metadata using code that helped get this running that you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: BTW, the code as posted ran just fine on localhost, but didn't work across the network.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Did your service url have an IP address of `0` or `0.0.0.0`? If not, it might not be binding to the right IP. You also need to add a firewall exception for the appropriate port(s)

Comment: Nope.  Not it.  As noted in the comments below the question, the issue was in my metadata.